# Unable to find package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.6.2.3'

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I'm using swagger, but I have this problem according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). The nuget package has not been downloaded successfully. What should I do?

This is the error message:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> The feed'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists
> package'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.6.2.3' but multiple attempts
> to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or
> required packages were removed while the current operation was in
> progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again. Unable
> to find package'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.6.2.3'.

Update:

I try to use the command：Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 6.2.3

Error:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to execute the `Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 6.2.3` command in the Package Manager Console?

Comment: Have you installed .net 6 or visual studio 2022? You created a asp.net core 3.1 project? Because you didn't mention your code environment, just provided the error message, so I thought about the environment first, as the command is installing version 6.2.3. By the way, I test the command in my asp.net core 3.1 mvc project with vs2019, but I already installed 2022 version. And the command worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a problem on your internet connection? Package seems exist (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/6.2.3).

Comment: I can download normally now, it seems to be caused by the network, thank you!